# how to launch the new virtualEnv

Tags: python, django, virtualenv

I am trying to setup a new virtual env to work with django and flask.

installed

```
sudo pip install virtualenv
sudo pip install virtualenvwrapper
```

for some raisons, overlapping with anaconda.

This command doesn't work out.

```
virtualenv newThing
```

While this command is working out.

```
virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python2.7 newThing
```

What should I add to .bash_profile to make it working reguarly ?

Comment: is anaconda your default python? I imagine if you check your .bashrc there will be an entry making anaconda your default, just remove that.

Answer (score 0):

That's probably the wrong question, as running a venv by default largely defeats the benefit of creating one.

To answer your question, though, you can enter a venv this way:

```
source newThing/bin/activate
```

Once you deploy this code to a server, you'll likely specify the venv to use in your WSGI conf.

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed virtualenvwrapper as you say then you need to add some bits to your bash config:

```
# Virtualenv
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
export WORKON_HOME="$HOME/.virtualenvs"
```

This ensures you source the bash script for the wrapper commands to call in bash and sets the location to use to store and access your virtual envs.

Now to create a virtualenv you can run the wrapper commmand `mkvirtualenv` and then the name of your desired env.

Then to switch to that env to work on your project run `workon` and then the name of that env.

There are a bunch of other useful wrapper commands like setting your project directory for example - this is useful when you are switching between projects which use different env.

For this try activating an venv using `workon` and then `cd` to the working directory for the project and then running `setvirtualenvproject` - this then remembers that directory to switch to whenever you run `workon` for that venv.